# Two Op Amp In-Amp Voltage output

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I mounted the following circuit using a LM324, where Val = 5v, Vref = 1.78v, R6=18K and R7=10K.

I measured Vu and i'm getting a very close value to Vref, why?

[image: Circuit layout]

Edit: V- and V+ are connected to Vref when i measure Vu.
I mounted a capacitor (not shown in the schematic) of value 50nF between the power supply and ground as close as possible to the operational amplifier.

The resistors have the following values: R4=R2=8.8KOhm and R1=R3=2.2KOhm

Comment: Can you derive the theoretical output?

Comment: How are the \$V_{REF}\$ input and \$V_{REF}\$ output related? And whet about the missing voltages and component values?

Comment: @Eugene Sh Yes with R4=R2 and R3=R1 without R5 the transfer function is (1+R2/R1) with R5 is  (1+R2/R1) + 2R2/R5